# Second if-condition needs to check for null value in the same row

Tags: python, pandas, csv, if-statement, while-loop

I've been looking for a solution to check if the value in a different column but the same row as the input value's column is null.

I'm using a while loop and need to have 2 conditions in the if and else statements. My first condition on checking whether the input value exists in the dataframe works, but I can't solve the second condition.

The 2 conditions are: the input value must exist in the staff column (done), and the input value's same row as the leftdate column's must be null.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
while True:
    staffName = input("Please key in a staff's full name: ")
    if (first_df['Staff'] == staffName).any() and (first_df['LeftDate'] == None):
        print(staffName + " is a current staff of the organization.")
        exit = input("Would you like to key in another staff's full name? (Y/N): ")
        if (exit == 'N'):
            print("Thank you for using the organization's staff records system.")
            break
        else:
            staffName
    elif (first_df['Staff'] == staffName).any():
        print(staffName + " was a previous staff of the organization.")
        exit = input("Would you like to key in another staff's full name? (Y/N): ")
        if (exit == 'N'):
            print("Thank you for using the organization's staff records system.")
            break
        else:
            staffName
```

Comment: `(first_df['Staff'] == staffName & first_df['LeftDate'] == None).any()`?

Comment: Hey @Barmar, thank you for that, I really appreciate it! I tried it and but got a TypeError. Also, my second condition has to check for null value in the same row as the input staffName and not the entire LeftDate column

Comment: It needs parentheses to override operator precedence. `((first_df['Staff'] == staffName) & (first_df['LeftDate'] == None)).any()` It should be checking both conditions in the same row. Each comparison returns a series, and `&` combines the series row by row.

Comment: This explanation really helped me to also manage the elif statement. Thank you so much for the help, @Barmar !

Comment: `None` and `NaN` are two completely different things, you should clarify the question.